# Make name tags dynamically in Sketch

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

So I'm creating a name tag for a conference where I have 250 participants.

Each name tag needs a different name, location, a specific color of a square and a question.

Is there any way I can program or a get an addon that does this for me, so I don't have to do it 250 times individually?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a plugin that can do exactly what you want, but with the "[sketch craft](https://www.invisionapp.com/craft)" plugin you can add a file in json format and give it a text value. And you can duplicate this text and automatically get it in other information. But it seems that the color value can not be assigned as the color value of an object in json format.